# The pipeline operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pipeline

Will the pipeline operator enable the composition of functions?

```
const sum = (nos)=> nos.reduce((p,c)=> p + (+c), 0);
const avg = (nos)=> sum(nos) / nos.length;
const tail = ([_, ...tail])=> tail; 
const tailAndAverage = tail |> avg; // valid?
```

Is `tailAndAverage` a function in the above code?

Comment: Not according to the proposal: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator .

Comment: Try instead: `const tailAndAverage = _ => _ |> tail |> avg;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - to quote the proposal:

> The pipeline operator is essentially a useful syntactic sugar on a function call with a single argument. In other words, sqrt(64) is equivalent to 64 |> sqrt.

So your example would effectively just end up desugaring to `avg(tail)`, which isn't what you want.

That said, there are also two separate proposals to add a composition operator to the language:

- https://github.com/TheNavigateur/proposal-pipeline-operator-for-function-composition
- https://github.com/isiahmeadows/function-composition-proposal